# Extracting arrays into lists

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, list, foreach

I'm trying to extract each sub array using the foreach as list command.

Updated:

I am now trying this:

```
  foreach ($data as $element) {
  list($id,$ownerid,$owner,$coords,$name,$score,$citytype,$location) = $element;
  findcontinent($coords);
  echo $coords;
  echo '<br>';
  echo $cont;
  echo '<br>';}
```

the function I am calling is as follows. I know this function works when I statically call a specific coordinate from the array $data[0]['coords'] for example.

```
function findcontinent($coords){
            $tc2 = explode(":",$coords);
            $tcx = (int)(trim($tc2[0],"'\'"));
            $tcy = (int)(trim($tc2[1],"'"));
            $tcx2 = round((($tcx)*(600/383)),0);
            $tcy2 = round((($tcy)*(600/360)),0);

            if($tcx2 < 100) // checking for continents ending with 0
            {
            $tcx3 = '0';
            $xtrans = substr((string)$tcx3,0,1);
            }
            else
            {
            $xtrans = substr((string)$tcx2,0,1);
            }           

            if($tcy2 < 100) // checking for continents starting with 0
            {
            $tcy3 = '0';
            $ytrans = substr((string)$tcy3,0,1);
            }
            else
            {
            $ytrans = substr((string)$tcy2,0,1);
            }
    $cont = C.$ytrans.$xtrans;
    return($cont);

}
```

I then want to run a set of SQL commands to update a DB. Do I have the correct syntax?

My array is as follows - sample. The actual datasets could be dynamic, many individual sub arrays?

```
[data] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 16515340
                [owner_id] => 3475
                [owner] => Player1
                [coords] => '268:252
                [name] => AC2013
                [score] => 11863
                [city_type] => castle
                [location] => land
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 16515335
                [owner_id] => 3475
                [owner] => Player1
                [coords] => '263:252
                [name] => AC2013
                [score] => 7
                [city_type] => castle
                [location] => water
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 17891610
                [owner_id] => 3523
                [owner] => Player2
                [coords] => '282:273
                [name] => City of Repoman9900
                [score] => 1978
                [city_type] => castle
                [location] => water
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 10616856
                [owner_id] => 73
                [owner] => Player2
                [coords] => '024:162
                [name] => 1killer
                [score] => 1308
                [city_type] => castle
                [location] => water
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [id] => 10813465
                [owner_id] => 2862
                [owner] => Player3
                [coords] => '025:165
                [name] => City of vuvuzea991
                [score] => 1091
                [city_type] => castle
                [location] => land
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [id] => 17367317
                [owner_id] => 84
                [owner] => Player4
                [coords] => '277:265
                [name] => Dreadland
                [score] => 776
                [city_type] => castle
                [location] => water
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2162850
                [owner_id] => 2989
                [owner] => Player5
                [coords] => '162:033
                [name] => City of Dinoeyez
                [score] => 157
                [city_type] => castle
                [location] => water
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2818192
                [owner_id] => 556
                [owner] => Player6
                [coords] => '144:043
                [name] => City of wildfire123
                [score] => 7
                [city_type] => castle
                [location] => water
            )

    )
```

Since it looks like associative arrays cannot be exploded into lists, which would have been nice, trying to run this loop to extract even 1 record, and failing

$count = 0;
// loop to cycle through array

```
foreach($data as $data=>$inner_array){
    $c2 = (string)$count;   
    $id = $data[$count]['id'];
    echo $id;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $count;
    echo '<br>';    
 //then increment counter and move to next
     $count = $count+1;
    }
```

The counters return just fine, but I cannot seem to parse any of the variables in the sub-array.  Echo output is as follows:

`<br>0<br><br>1<br><br>2<br><br>3<br><br>4<br><br>5<br>`

The data set I am using right now is 6 sub-arrays, so I know it is going through the loop correctly.

Comment: Where did you get the syntax from? You should perhaps spend a little more time reading the documentation - for this example, the [page on foreach structures](http://php.net/foreach) should help.

Comment: i got the syntax from http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php, the section on Unpacking nested arrays with list().  According to what I can make out, and I admit freely I am a novice here, you can put the as list directly in the foreach, which is what I have tried. @Barmar

Comment: I didn't realize `list` was allowed there, I've updated my answer to use it.

Comment: ... Allowed from 5.5 which is still in beta.

Comment: It was the `$data => inner_array` part that I was questioning :-)

Comment: which works in a loop, and counts through an array. I tested it and ran that bit. however, due to immense patience from @Barmar I now have my solution. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ($data as list($id,$ownerid,$owner,$coords,$name,$score,$citytype,$location)) {
  // commands
}
```

Since this use of `list` is only allowed in the beta version of PHP, the more portable syntax requires two steps:

```
foreach ($data as $element) {
  list($id,$ownerid,$owner,$coords,$name,$score,$citytype,$location) = $element;
  // commands
}
```

`foreach ($data=>inner_array as xxx)` is not valid. The var=>var syntax is only valid after `as`, not before it. I'm not sure why you have nested for loops -- there's only one array you need to iterate over.

I would be very wary of using this syntax when the sub-arrays are associative arrays. List assignment is based on the order of elements in the sub-array, it doesn't try to match variable names with keys. So if you have a sub-array where the `owner_id` element is before the `id` element, the list assignment will set `$id` to the owner ID, and `$owner_id` to the ID. The order of elements in an associative array is the order they were added to the array (unless you've used a function to rearrange them, such as `array_sort()` or `array_splice()`), so unless you're sure you always add keys in the same order this can be dangerous.

UPDATE:

List assignment like this doesn't work with associative arrays. According to [PHP list documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php):

> **list()** only works on numerical arrays and assumes the numerical indices start at 0.

So you'll need to assign the variables individually:

```
foreach ($data as $element) {
  $id = $element['id'];
  $owner_id = $element['owner_id'];
  // and so on
}
```

Comment: The sub array format is fixed, and the same for each sub array, so the order will not change. Question, will just $data allow me to loop through each of the sub-arrays and dynamically pick up the values?

Comment: You don't appear to have a variable called `$data`. Your top-level is an associative array with an element whose key is `data`, so I referred to that as `$array['data']` in my answer.

Comment: i have defined $data as a variable in my code. basically what I have is `$data=$_POST['data']` defined. now i want loop through $data and dynamically extract the sub array values and run calcs, post to DB.  What I have posted here is just the contents of $_POST['data'] because the rest of the information is not relevant to what I am processing.

Comment: So where I have `$array['data']` you can use `$data`.

Comment: do i need to encaspulate it at '`$data'` or just `$data` will do?; and what does the =$element do on the next line?

Comment: This is basic PHP. If you want to access a variable, you just say the variable name. Quoting it prevents variable expansion. Is this your first `foreach` loop?

Comment: Once you do `$data = $_POST['data']` you just refer to it as `$data`. You seem to be very confused about the difference between variables and array keys.

Comment: 7 days into PHP programming. Used to code, but not in the recent past. Updated the question to reflect the code but I see that the as list parameter may not be active, still in beta.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Add `ini_set('error_reporting', -1); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the top of the script.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to do it in traditional PHP.

Comment: thanks. i have updated the content of the question to reflect the code I will now test.

Comment: You shouldn't do that, it makes it hard for future readers of the question to understand it.

Comment: @MichaelRushton PHP Fatal error:  Directive 'magic_quotes_gpc' is no longer available in PHP in Unknown on line 0

Comment: That's unrelated to this question. Magic quotes is an obsolete PHP configuration option, you should take it out of your setup.

Comment: ok. but a dev environment. right let me add some more context. I am writing an api so this PHP doesn't run direct on my localhost. I have to call it from a webpage running an add-on script.  When I try to access directly, it should return 'unknown origin'. Right now I am getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'header' (T_STRING) in /var/www/aix/api_clean2.php on line 8 when I try to access the page directly as a test.

Comment: You're not assigning the result of `findcontinent()` to the variable. Error reporting would tell you that the variable `$cont` isn't defined.

Comment: `foreach ($data as $element) {
  list($id,$ownerid,$owner,$coords,$name,$score,$citytype,$location) = $element;
  echo $id;
  echo '<br>';}` returns `<br><br><br><br><br><br>` in echo. not even running the findcontinent() function right now, just testing the foreach. and in findcontinent $cont is defined and returned.

Comment: ah i c. do you mean I have to call findcontinent like this: `$continent=findcontinent($coords);' and the returned value gets stored in a variable?. Regardless that is a second step right now. First I need to be sure of extracting the data, then manipulating it can come after.

Comment: It looks like list assignment doesn't work with associative arrays at all.

Comment: that last comment you provided was the key. thanks that worked like a charm.